# A specific combination of pre and code tags breaks the page

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown

As a Preamble *DO NOT DO THIS*. If you find a bug, do remember to undo the damage and report responsibly..

I just had to edit a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361563/135565)(now deleted) that *horribly* broke the sandbox.  I had to figure out how to fix this, and a workaround for people with mod and editing powers is to replace the markdown with a placeholder that's not broken, once you find the edit button. If things are completely irrecoverably broken, if you can find the post ID, you can also do the/posts/post_id/edit route.

Now, amongst other things, it ruins the page controls

[image]

(If any other mods come across this, that edit link *works* and you can edit *then* delete... )

And the rest of the question

[image]

it also breaks the revisions page for that revision slightly

[image]

I mean, it breaks the edit page slightly too

Also seems to break the footer where the triggering content exists

[image]

Posted for documentation purposes, and status reviewed and deleted the post that triggered it so no one gets ideas. :)

Comment: The devs can see the original. ugh. Now I need to figure out where the edit button is

Comment: unbroke it - since its pretty badly messed to the point people can't do things. I REALLY do mean the bit about *RESPONSIBLE* disclosure, and being able to fix what you broke. That means a meta post, and editing out the breakage.

Comment: Related: [Should we set restrictions on what answers can be posted to the Formatting Sandbox?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308511/should-we-set-restrictions-on-what-answers-can-be-posted-to-the-formatting-sandb)

Comment: Actually was more concerned with someone else doing this outside the sandbox.

Comment: That makes sense. By the way, a few days ago, I came across a deleted answer to the Sandbox that was doing the same thing, and I stubbed that one out as well.

Comment: Adding this to the bug duty rotation to be looked into. Thanks!